# Server Error while ruuning python script on XAMPP

Tags: python, mysql, xampp, bottle

I have written a python script to fetch all data from a table called `users` in a database. I am using xampp server and mysql. When I am trying to run the script it is giving me an error:

```
Server error!

The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request.

Error message: 
End of script output before headers: test3.py

If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.

Error 500

localhost
Apache/2.4.12 (Unix) OpenSSL/1.0.1p PHP/5.6.11 mod_perl/2.0.8-dev Perl/v5.16.3
```

Here is the python script i have written using bottle framework:

```
#!/Python27/python

from bottle import route, run
import json
import MySQLdb as db

@route('/users', method = 'GET')
def getUser():
    c = db.connect('localhost','root','','temp')
    cur = c.cursor()
    sql1 = 'SELECT * FROM Users;'
    cur.execute(sql1)
    result = cur.fetchall();
    c.commit()
    c.close()

    j= json.dumps(result)
    return j
```

Comment: did you test your mysql??? I mean in your xampp  output it doesn't show any mysql version...

Comment: yeah its basically the problem of importing MySQLdb can you tell me how to make this dependency

Comment: no its not about importing mysqldb that would have shown import error not internal server error. The question is did you use mysql in you xamp, did you create any table through raw queries? or through xamp interface?

Comment: yes i have created table in databse and access it using queries

Comment: The reason i doubt is that your xamp error only shows apache,perl,php and no mysql. Oh if you know php can you write some basic code to access the mysql like creating or reading a table?

Comment: @Ja8zyjits I have written the php code to access data from table in database and it is showing the data.

Comment: Can you show your bottle terminal output also? and the process you followed for running your bottle app. Paste it in your question.